# remove hyphen in bash prompt

Tags: bash, prompt

My bash PS1 prompt is configured as:

```
export PS1="\e[1;38;5;120m\\n\s \V\\$ \e[0m"
```

It looks like

```
-bash 5.0.7$
```

Having the hyphen, `-`, in front of `bash` is quite annoying. Does anyone know how I can get rid of it?

Comment: Don't use bash as login shell to avoid leading `-`.

Comment: There's no need to export `PS1`. Put it in `.bashrc`, and every interactive shell will define it as needed without inheriting it from a parent process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `-` appears because the `login` program runs your default shell with a prefixed `-` to indicate that a login shell should be used (equivalent to `bash -l`).

`\s` is essentially just a synonym for `basename "$0"`. If you can't easily change how your shell is run in the first place, you can modify  your prompt to strip the `-` from `$0` instead.

```
PS1="\e[1;38;5;120m\\n${0#-} \V\\$ \e[0m"
```

(Unless you specify otherwise, I'll assume no other processing of `$0` is needed.)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe not exactly what you had in mind, but replacing `\s` with literal text `bash` will do that:

`export PS1="\e[1;38;5;120m\\nbash \V\\$ \e[0m"`

Setting the prompt like this wouldn't work for other shells anyway.

Comment: How do I make sure that setting the prompt will work for other shells?

Comment: @flashburn Which shells, specifically?

Comment: @flashburn It depends on the shell since they configure prompts differently. /bin/sh will use PS1 but won't support bash escape sequences.

Comment: @GoogleFail To clarify for myself. There are no standard settings that are supported by all the shells? Am I correct?

Comment: Heck, `export` isn't even supported by *all* shells. Or the `var=...` syntax for setting variables.

Comment: Bourne-style shells vary wildly in how they will preprocess the value of `PS1`. The POSIX specification only lists two special expandables: `!` is replaced with the current history number, and `!!` is a literal `!`. `ksh` and `dash` stick with that; `zsh` has a large but completely different list than `bash` (they are all prefixed with `%`, not a backslash). Customer prompts are a very shell-specific feature.

Comment: Note that the color codes are not a special prompt feature; those are just ANSI escape codes processed by the terminal, no matter what produces them.